# Vegas Pro 12 vs Vegas Pro 12 Premium

Tags: software-recommendation, vegas-pro

I'm currently shopping for Sony Vegas Pro 12 and I'm slightly confused at what I am finding. In addition to the standard Vegas Pro, I've found a "Premium" version that contains some upgrades (SoundForge 11, 180 days of support) but at a drastically reduced price (50% of the standard).

The premium version isn't even on Sony's website, so I'm guessing it was made for independent retailers.

Is there a difference between Vegas Pro 12 and Vegas Pro 12 Premium? Or is this just a great deal?

Comment: I couldn't find any more details about it than you.  It appears to be available from multiple reputable retailers, but I'd probably try contacting Sony first to verify it.  It may just actually be a very good deal as they are trying to break in to a market place largely controlled by Adobe.  They've been making a lot of growth lately and this may just be a tactic for trying to get further gains.  With Adobe going subscription only and Apple pretty much abandoning the professional market, it's certainly the right time for it.

Comment: You're probably right. I just cashed in some credit card rewards, so once I get those Amazon gift cards I will buy it and post my findings.

Comment: On it's way, I'll give an official answer by the end the of week!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After purchasing Sony Vegas Pro 12 Premium I can confirm that **it DOES include the full version of Sony Vegas Pro 12!**

This really is a great deal as it also includes DVD Architect Pro 6.0, Sound Forge Pro 11.0, and CD Architect 5.2.